# why map frame isn't continuous

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I try to understand the different coordinate frame in ROS.
I see a explication of map frame like follow,**
*"The coordinate frame called map is a world fixed frame, with its Z-axis pointing upwards. The pose of a mobile platform, relative to the map frame, should not significantly drift over time. The map frame is not continuous, meaning the pose of a mobile platform in the map frame can change in discrete jumps at any time.
In a typical setup, a localization component constantly re-computes the robot pose in the map frame based on sensor observations, therefore eliminating drift, but causing discrete jumps when new sensor information arrives.
The map frame is useful as a long-term global reference, but discrete jumps make it a poor reference frame for local sensing and acting."*
**So my question is why the map frame is not continuous? Isn't all the coordinate frame continuous?
thx**

http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220432/why-map-frame-isn%27t-continuous/) by [huang0171](https://answers.ros.org/users/23561/huang0171/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means that the function of the robot pose in the map frame is not a continuous function. In other words it can jump. The reason for that is written in the paragraph you cited. This is in contrast to, for example, odometry, which is usually continuous.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0